# Call number method with two dots in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why

```
123.toString()
```

throws an SyntaxError

while

```
123..toString()
```

is not?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first `.` you type in a Number literal is the decimal point.

Comment: `123..toString()` is equivalent to `(123).toString()` :)

Comment: why doesn't 10.0..toString() work? should result in a string "10.0"

Comment: @Ricky-U Dot-notation syntax is “value dot property-name” not “value dot dot property-name”

Comment: yes i'm aware of dot notation syntax, but if the first . is a number literal representation a decimal point, then why 10.0..toString() does not work?  and 10..toString() works.

Comment: @Ricky-U — Yes, the **first** dot is the decimal point is but `10.0..toString()` has **three** dots in it. The second expects a property name after it, not another dot.